# NDA: No publicity, to keep a relationship confidential, legal terms clause?

Tags: non-disclosure

I couldn't find an example of clause for an NDA to also keep the said NDA and the business relations secret/confidential.

I could get harm if the business relation is disclosed publicly or to other external persons.

What would be such clause in legal terms?

Comment: My boss signed such an NDA many years ago. A very large company promised not to sue for X, but we had to keep this promise unpublished unles they sued us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Such a clause would be called a non-disclosure clause

There’s nothing particularly special about what you want, any commercial lawyer could draft it for you.

Comment: Thanks! Not a huge amount of money is in the balance to search, wait for and pay a lawyer. A `non-disclosure of agreement` search gives me what I wanted. Thanks again!

Comment: It feels very weird for something to be important enough to justify a signed agreement but not important enough to require a lawyer.  It's not like you could reasonably enforce (i.e., sue for violation) such an agreement without a lawyer.